# Synthesis of silver nanoparticles

Tags: nanotechnology

Synthesis of silver nanoparticles  by electrochemical Method

[image]

The silver content in these products consists of both silver ions and silver particles. Typically 90% of silver content is in the form of ionic silver and the remaining 10% of the silver content is in the form of silver particles. The silver ions are produced by electrolysis are frequently described as "dissolved silver". Because the majority of the silver in these products is dissolved silver rather than metallic silver particles, it would be more technically accurate to describe these products as silver solutions. In the present work, the electrochemical synthesis of silver nanoparticles is presented.

Tech.Journal,Vol.33,Part(B),No.7,2015

Q.1  What is the scientific meaning of the following sentence?

"The duration used for exchanging the polarity was 4 min."

Q.2 How can we exchange the D.C current polarity regularly?

Q.3 What is the suitable current and any other conditions for preparing silver nanoparticles?

Q.4 How can we extract silver nanoparticles from silver solutions?